# What does this ifeq makefile statement do?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What does this makefile code part do?

```
ifeq ($(VERB),)
    HIDE := @
else
    HIDE := 
endif
```

I think that the condition itself checks whether variable `VERB` is NOT assigned with anything (correct)? but then what does the `@` assignment does to `HIDE`?

The `HIDE` variable is then used this way:

```
$(HIDE)$(call custom-command,$(@D))
```

What will be the difference for the output, depending on how the `HIDE` is assigned?

Comment: Presumably `$(HIDE)` is used subsequently in the Makefile to inhibit the `make` default to print commands as they are being executed. (This is by and large unnecessary; use `make -s` if you don't want to see what it's doing.) See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recipe-Echoing

Comment: Thats true. What I meant more is what is the `@` assignement doing here exactly?

Comment: It is assigning the string `@` as the value of the variable `HIDE`. How is that unclear?

Comment: I have added more details to the question to provide better context. I understand that this is somewhat about not printing the commands output to the stdout, but I do not understand how it is done exactly here.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it... The `@` in front of a command will suppress the output to the stdout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefixing a recipe line with `@` tells `make` to execute it silently. (See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recipe-Echoing)

As a crude example;

```
.PHONY: demo
demo:
    @echo foo
    echo bar
```

When you `make demo`, you see

```
foo
echo bar
bar
```

Now, if you parametrize the `@` into a variable

```
HIDE := @

.PHONY: demo
demo:
    $(HIDE)echo foo
    echo bar
```

the effect is still exactly the same.

In the example you show, the variable is set conditionally; so it can be empty if `VERB` is set and nonempty, or it will be set to `@` if `VERB` is unset or empty, and thus hide the default output from `make` for those commands in particular which are prefixed by `$(HIDE)`.

Comment: Does the `VERB` need to be set with anything? Even 0? Or does it have to be non zero?

Comment: `ifeq` can be finicky; but in your example, it checks whether the value is empty, which it will be if it's unset, or if the value is literally the empty string. Updated the answer to be more precise.

Comment: In `make` in general, there is no concept of 0 being false, etc.  In make everything is a string: there aren't any such thing as numbers (except in very specific contexts of functions that accept numbers).  So to make 0 is no different from a or any other character when it comes to conditionals.  Since make is string-based, what's important are string equality, and "empty strings" and "non-empty strings".  For `ifeq` etc., string equality is all that matters (hence the `eq`).  For the `$(if ..)` function "empty strings" are false and "non-empty strings" are true.